# Scheme: how to create simple "Ouija Board" (string procedures)

Tags: scheme

Using the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ". Initially starting on the index "0" of the alphabet, I am to keep track of each time the "planchette" moves left or right. If the planchette hovers, then I am to record that letter. I am to use string-length, string-ref, and list->string in my function.

```
(define alphabet "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

(trace-define ouija
  (lambda (ls1 ls2)
    (ouija-help ls1 alphabet 0)))

(trace-define ouija-help
  (lambda (ls1 ls2 x)
    (cond
      [(and (equal? (car ls1) 'left) (equal? (string-ref ls2 x) 'a)) (list->string (cons 'a (ouija-help (cdr ls1) ls2 x)))]
      [(and (equal? (car ls1) 'right) (equal? (string-ref ls2 x) 'z)) (list->string (cons 'z (ouija-help (cdr ls1) ls2 x)))]
      [(equal? (car ls1) 'right) (string-ref (string-ref ls2 x) (+ x 1))]
      [(equal? (car ls1) 'left) (string-ref (string-ref ls2 x) (+ x 1))]
      [(equal? (car ls1) 'hover) (list->string (cons (string-ref ls2 x) (ouija-help (cdr ls1) ls2 x)))]
      )))
```

Examples of correct input/output:

~ (ouija '() alphabet)  
""

~(ouija '(hover) alphabet)  
"A"

~(ouija '(right hover hover hover hover hover) alphabet)  
"BBBBB"

~(ouija '(hover right hover right hover) alphabet)  
"ABC"

~(ouija '(right right right hover left hover left hover right hover) alphabet)  
"DCBC"

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this:

```
(define (ouija actions board)
  (define imax (- (string-length board) 1))
  (define (helper actions i)
    (if (null? actions)
        '()
        (case (car actions)
          ((hover) (cons (string-ref board i) (helper (cdr actions) i)))
          ((left)  (helper (cdr actions) (if (> i 0) (- i 1) i)))
          ((right) (helper (cdr actions) (if (< i imax) (+ i 1) i))))))
  (list->string (helper actions 0)))
```

or

```
(define helper
  (lambda (actions board i)
    (if (null? actions)
        '()
        (case (car actions)
          ((hover) (cons (string-ref board i) (helper (cdr actions) board i)))
          ((left)  (helper (cdr actions) board (if (> i 0) (- i 1) i)))
          ((right) (helper (cdr actions) board (if (< i (- (string-length board) 1)) (+ i 1) i)))))))

(define ouija
  (lambda (actions board)
    (list->string (helper actions board 0))))
```

Comment: Shoot I am really REALLY sorry... I completely forgot to include that I am not allowed to use the built-in procedures: reverse, length, append, or assoc.

Comment: Neither `string-length`?

Comment: I am to use string-length, string-ref, and list->string in my procedure.

Comment: So my last example is OK then?

Comment: I don't think we have covered loops yet. Is there a way to use recursion without loop?

Comment: That's no loop per se. It's just a procedure called loop. You can call it helper, or anything. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for the help :) Would you be willing to explain your defining of definitions within a definition?

Comment: A `define` inside another `define` is simply a *Local* definition, which means that the symbols `imax` and `helper` are only known inside `ouija`. Also, this way `imax` is known inside `helper` without passing it as a parameter. I've added a version that's more like your initial one.

Comment: Wow that's really helpful. Thank you for all your wonderful insight! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that is commonly used when implementing the tapes of Turing machines:

Turn the `alphabet` into a `list` and then take off the `car` and `cdr` splitting the list into three parts: `left`, `center`, `right`; thus unzipping the list. The actions effect the list in the same way as a list zipper.

Note that there are no indexes or even numbers.

```
(define (ouija-helper actions left center right)
  (if (null? actions) 
      '()
      (case (car actions)
        ((hover) (cons center (ouija-helper (cdr actions) left center right)))
        ((left) (if (null? left) 
                    (ouija-helper (cdr actions) left center right)
                    (ouija-helper (cdr actions) (cdr left) (car left) (cons center right))))
        ((right) (if (null? right) 
                     (ouija-helper (cdr actions) left center right)
                     (ouija-helper (cdr actions) (cons center left) (car right) (cdr right)))))))

(define (ouija actions alphabet) 
  (let ((alphabet (string->list alphabet)))
    (list->string (ouija-helper actions '() (car alphabet) (cdr alphabet)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't process the alphabet as you walk the 'hover' list; instead think of the 'hover' list as producing indices based on `left` -> subtract one and `right` -> add one.  With this the top-level function wold be:

```
(define ouija
  (lambda (actions alphabet)
     (list->string (map (lambda (index) (string-ref alphabet index))
                        (actions->indices actions 0)))))
```

Now, walk the actions to create a list of indices after adding or subtracting.

```
(define actions->indices
  (lambda (actions index)
    (if (null? actions)
        '()
        (let ((rest (cdr actions)))
          (case (car actions)
            ((hover) (cons index (actions->indices rest index)))
            ((left ) (actions->indices rest (- index 1)))
            ((right) (actions->indices rest (+ index 1))))))))


> (actions->indices '(hover hover) 0)
(0 0)
> (actions->indices '(hover right left hover) 0)
(0 0)
> (actions->indices '(right right hover right right hover) 0)
(2 4)
```

And then finally:

```
> (ouija '(hover right right hover) "ABCDEF")
"AC"
```